# If $x^{15}-x^{13}+x^{11}-x^9+x^7-x^5+x^3-x=7$, prove that $x^{16}>15$.

Tags: inequality, polynomials

"If $x^{15}-x^{13}+x^{11}-x^9+x^7-x^5+x^3-x=7$, prove that $x^{16}>15$."

The above problem came on a local question paper. I tried to solve it by factorizing and sum of G.P. , But I was unable to derive it. Sorry for my English.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you know about x? Is it integer, real?

Comment: @Eugen Covaci $x$ is real.

Comment: Perhaps you should multiply each side of the equation by $x^2$, and then use the original equation in order to reduce the amount of information (it gets you to $x^{17}=7x^2+7$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $x<-1$, then
$$
7=\frac{-x((-x^2)^8-1)}{-x^2-1}=\frac{x(x^{16}-1)}{x^2+1}
$$
and right side is negative, which is a contradiction. Also, if $-1\le x \le 0$, $\left|\frac{x(x^{16}-1)}{x^2+1}\right|\le 1$. Thus $x>0$. By AM-GM inequality,
$$
x^{16}=\frac{7x^2+7}{x}+1= 7x+\frac{7}{x}+1 \ge 2\cdot 7 + 1 = 15.
$$
If the equality holds, then $7x=\frac{7}{x}$, which means $x=1$, but it contradicts $x^{15}-x^{13}+\cdots+ x^3-x=7$. Thus $x^{16}>15$.

Comment: Thanks it will be a great help.

Answer (score 5):

If you multiply both sides by $x^2+1$ you get $$x^{17}-x=7(x^2+1)$$or $$x^{16}=1+7\frac{x^2+1}{x}.$$A little calculus shows that the right side is negative for all $x<0$. So $x>0$, and now again a little calculus shows that  $$x^{16}\ge1+7(2).$$Show that $x\ne1$ and it follows that $x^{16}>15.$

Answer (score 2):

Your expression is equivalent to
$$x \frac{x^{16}-1}{1+x^2}=7.$$
Then
$$x^{16}=7 \frac{1+x^2}{x}+1$$
notice that $x$ must be positive and that the min of $7 \frac{1+x^2}{x}+1$ on the positive real line is $15$.

Comment: I think your $1-x^{16}$ should be $x^{16}-1$.

Comment: I think you should obtain $1+x^{16}$  in the first fraction.

Comment: No, you still haven't done the multiplication correctly. (And btw the min of that whatsis on the positive axis is $13$, not $15$. You need to do the multiplication correctly to get $15$.)

Comment: Right. Of course that's exactly what I said...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you, the fact that the sum started with $-x$ misled me.